# @Html.Display not showing the data, only showing variable.property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a "productName" in my view.  The product name comes from my 'Product' table and is tied to my 'Kit' table through a FK relationship (KitId is a foreign key on the 'Product' table).

On a view for 'Kit' I am trying to display all of the products with that 'KitId'.  I can see that the data is being filtered correctly because there are 5 products with this 'Model.KitId'.

Here is where I am filtering and should be displaying the 'productName'.

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <dt>Product Name</dt>
    <dd>@Html.Display(product.ProductName)</dd>
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on `<dd>@Html.Display(product.ProductName)</dd>`

I can hover over product.ProductName and I can see that the 'ProductName' value is picking up the actual ProductName to display.

But when I run the application, I see the `<dt>Product Name</dt>` but `<dd>product.ProductName</dd>` is blank, there is no data displayed.

Not sure how to fix this. Should I be referencing `@Html.DisplayFor(something)`. I tried to do `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.something)' but there is no`model.productName` because that is not how my FK relationship is designed.

I can provide any other details if needed.

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => product.ProductName)` (or just `@product.ProductName`)

Comment: Yep that works and so does @Html.Raw().  I like your way better.  Because I would rather not use markup without encoding. Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason for `@Html.Raw()` unless the value contains html markup

Comment: Makes sense.  I will mark this as the answer if you want to put it under 'answer'.  Thanks again.

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation for [HtmlHelper.Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174.aspx)? It doesn't work because the helper is expecting an expression that translates to a model property or a key in ViewData. Or, put simply, you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes exactly like that Stephen Muecke :P (never saw that one come through actually....my bad. Fixed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.Raw(product.ProductName)` fixed this.  Not sure why `@Html.Raw()` worked and `@Html.Display()` didn't.  But it worked.  Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: WOW! This is asinine that I have to do @Html.Raw(err.ErrorMessage) in a foreach loop to display my errors instead of being able to use @Html.Display(err.ErrorMessage) in the for loop. Thanks for suggested fix!